# Checking that an email address is google based or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on rails application that take user email and check that if user email id is google based then it redirect to google login else it redirect to application login page.

example:

1) if it regular gmail email address like(example@gmail.com)

2) if it google apps based email address like(example@company.com where company.com uses google apps)

3) if it use any other email address like(example@yahoo.com or example@hotmail.com)

So,how can I check that the user mail is gmail based that fulfill my 1st & 2nd condition.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first and the last points you can use a simple regex and check if `domain=="google"` or `domain=="yahoo"`:

```
email = 'tired@mydomain.com'
domain = email.sub(/.+@([^.]+).+/, '\1')
```

The upper lines will extract only `mydomain`. You can add a condition later to check whether is gmail / yahoo.

As for the second point you could `dig` the emails' MX records (you can check how this can be done in ruby). Here's the flow:

```
$> dig domainname.com mx
```

If they're with Google, you'll know it.

```
domainname.com.            2198    IN      MX      10 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.
domainname.com.            2198    IN      MX      20 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.
domainname.com.            2198    IN      MX      20 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.
domainname.com.            2198    IN      MX      30 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.com.
domainname.com.            2198    IN      MX      30 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.com.
domainname.com.            2198    IN      MX      30 ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.com.
domainname.com.            2198    IN      MX      30 ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.com.
```

Comment: `'tired@mydomain.com'[/(?<=@)\w+(?=\.)/] #⇒ 'mydomain'`. Global (why global?) sub is superfluous here.

Comment: @mudasobwa You're right. Mistakenly added it. I've made the necessary change.